# Is there any method to obtain the Hidden Weapon Spell other than ranking in the Bell Keepers?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm currently just missing that sorcery and about to start NG++, and I was wondering if there's any other way to obtain it in a fashion such as the Great Chaos Fireball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't do it other than through ranking...alternatively, you can just get them offline, that's what I did.

Comment: @Ozmah He probably means ranking the covenant offline by killing the sometimes spawning red phantom in Belfry Sol, if you don't want to play real PVP fights. The answer is phrased a bit vaguely, but I can confirm that ranking up is the only way to obtain the sorcery according to the official guide.

Comment: @Dominic De Coco, thank you for that, I've done some research regarding the phantom you mentioned and it seems that the strategy might work.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no other way to obtain Hidden Weapon. It's not too hard to get it as the covenant is pretty much like being part of a gank squad .